# Testing if a character exists with Regex

Tags: regex, vue.js

I have a few strings that I am trying to match against

1. Cafe Team Member: Grovedale (Featured)
2. Cafe Team Member: Barwon Heads (Featured)
3. Cafe Team Member: Barwon Heads

What I have been able to come up with is `/(?<=\:\s)(.+)(?=\s\()/g` which will work for options one and two but 3 (because I am looking for an open bracket after the location) it will not work. I am stumped about how else I could go about this.

[Where i have been testing](https://regexr.com/4aofr)

Edit:

Figured all i needed to add was `|$` so it now looks like `/(?<=\:\s)(.+)(?=\s\(|$)/g` but when testing it in codepen it still isn't capturing the string correctly. Where [regexr](https://regexr.com/4aofr) is saying it should work.

```js
// vue stuff
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        titles: [
          "Cafe Team Member: Grovedale (Featured)",
          "Cafe Team Member: Barwon Heads (Featured)",
          "Cafe Team Member: Barwon Heads",
        ]
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="title in titles">
    <p>{{ title.match(/(?<=\:\s)(.+)(?=\s\(|$)/g) }}</p>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regex:

```
(?<=:\s)[^(\r\n]+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3i84m/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=:\s)` - positive lookbehind to match the position immediately preceded by a `:` followed by a white-space
- `[^(\r\n]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is neither a `(` nor the newline characters. This will make sure to match all the characters until `(` is found in the same line. If `(` is not found, it matches till end of line.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't match just because `.+` must be followed with `?`, which match as few times as possible. Without it, `(.+)` will match until the end of line and your positive lookahead will not match anything.

```js
// vue stuff
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        titles: [
          "Cafe Team Member: Grovedale (Featured)",
          "Cafe Team Member: Barwon Heads (Featured)",
          "Cafe Team Member: Barwon Heads",
        ]
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="title in titles">
    <p>{{ title.match(/(?<=\:\s)(.+?)(?=\s\(|$)/g) }}</p>
  </template>
</div>
```